# Android app works on real phone but not on the emulator - Android Development?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-layout, emulation

I have tested my app on my sony x8 phone and it works perfectly well, however it does not work in the emulator, I tried to reinstall the android emulator,removed etc...

It's very annoying. The error I say on the emulator when I open my app is stops unexpectedly.

Please help.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@drawable/mainbgg"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="220dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_gravity="left"
    android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:src="@drawable/headingmain" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="20dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="102dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:src="@drawable/headingby" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView3"
    android:layout_width="120dp"
    android:layout_height="125dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="27dp"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:src="@drawable/ballmain" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/MainMenu"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dip"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.35"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
        android:background="@drawable/playbutton"
        android:src="@drawable/playbutton" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
        android:background="@drawable/helpbutton"
        android:src="@drawable/helpbutton" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
        android:background="@drawable/aboutbutton"
        android:src="@drawable/aboutbutton" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Here is the activity.java:

```
package com.sunny.studios.marton.seoul.uefaquiz;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;

 public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

    }
```

And the logcat:

```
Don't you think the problem is : java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity  this????

09-17 20:32:26.892: D/dalvikvm(296): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 801 objects / 58504 bytes in 56ms
09-17 20:32:28.333: E/dalvikvm-heap(296): 19180800-byte external allocation too large for this process.
09-17 20:32:28.333: E/GraphicsJNI(296): VM won't let us allocate 19180800 bytes
09-17 20:32:28.333: D/AndroidRuntime(296): Shutting down VM
09-17 20:32:28.343: W/dalvikvm(296): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
09-17 20:32:28.543: E/AndroidRuntime(296): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-17 20:32:28.543: E/AndroidRuntime(296): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.sunny.studios.marton.seoul.uefaquiz/com.sunny.studios.marton.seoul.uefaquiz.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #19: Error inflating class <unknown>
09-17 20:32:28.543: E/AndroidRuntime(296):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
09-17 20:32:28.543: E/AndroidRuntime(296):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
09-17 20:32:28.543: E/AndroidRuntime(296):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
09-17 20:32:28.543: E/AndroidRuntime(296):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
09-17 20:32:28.543: E/AndroidRuntime(296):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-17 20:32:28.543: E/AndroidRuntime(296):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
09-17 20:32:28.543: E/AndroidRuntime(296):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
09-17 20:32:28.543: E/AndroidRuntime(296):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-17 20:32:28.543: E/AndroidRuntime(296):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
09-17 20:32:28.543: E/AndroidRuntime(296):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
09-17 20:32:28.543: E/AndroidRuntime(296):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
09-17 20:32:28.543: E/AndroidRuntime(296):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-17 20:32:28.543: E/AndroidRuntime(296): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #19: Error inflating class <unknown>
09-17 20:32:28.543: E/AndroidRuntime(296):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:513)
09-17 20:32:28.543: E/AndroidRuntime(296):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
09-17 20:32:28.543: E/AndroidRuntime(296):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:563)
09-17 20:32:28.543: E/AndroidRuntime(296):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:618)
09-17 20:32:28.543: E/AndroidRuntime(296):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:407)
09-17 20:32:28.543: E/AndroidRuntime(296):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
09-17 20:32:28.543: E/AndroidRuntime(296):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
09-17 20:32:28.543: E/AndroidRuntime(296):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:198)
09-17 20:32:28.543: E/AndroidRuntime(296):  at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1647)
09-17 20:32:28.543: E/AndroidRuntime(296):  at com.sunny.studios.marton.seoul.uefaquiz.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:12)
09-17 20:32:28.543: E/AndroidRuntime(296):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
09-17 20:32:28.543: E/AndroidRuntime(296):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
09-17 20:32:28.543: E/AndroidRuntime(296):  ... 11 more
09-17 20:32:28.543: E/AndroidRuntime(296): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
09-17 20:32:28.543: E/AndroidRuntime(296):  at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:108)
09-17 20:32:28.543: E/AndroidRuntime(296):  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
09-17 20:32:28.543: E/AndroidRuntime(296):  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:446)
09-17 20:32:28.543: E/AndroidRuntime(296):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:500)
09-17 20:32:28.543: E/AndroidRuntime(296):  ... 22 more
09-17 20:32:28.543: E/AndroidRuntime(296): Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget
09-17 20:32:28.543: E/AndroidRuntime(296):  at android.graphics.Bitmap.nativeCreate(Native Method)
09-17 20:32:28.543: E/AndroidRuntime(296):  at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:468)
09-17 20:32:28.543: E/AndroidRuntime(296):  at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:435)
09-17 20:32:28.543: E/AndroidRuntime(296):  at android.graphics.Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(Bitmap.java:340)
09-17 20:32:28.543: E/AndroidRuntime(296):  at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.finishDecode(BitmapFactory.java:488)
09-17 20:32:28.543: E/AndroidRuntime(296):  at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:462)
09-17 20:32:28.543: E/AndroidRuntime(296):  at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:323)
09-17 20:32:28.543: E/AndroidRuntime(296):  at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:697)
09-17 20:32:28.543: E/AndroidRuntime(296):  at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1709)
09-17 20:32:28.543: E/AndroidRuntime(296):  at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:601)
09-17 20:32:28.543: E/AndroidRuntime(296):  at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:118)
09-17 20:32:28.543: E/AndroidRuntime(296):  ... 26 more
```

Comment: I think it's going to be that "Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: bitmap..." down near the bottom of your logcat. Jives pretty well with the device vs emulator dissonance.

Comment: when you create a virtual device, you can set memory size. probably it's not big enough. Try to make memory size bigger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open Android Virtual Device Manager -> New or Edit -> Memory Options. Check whether RAM & VM Heap are big enough?

Comment: Yeah it works thank you so much you are the best, but can it be a problem on some older android phones?

Answer (score 1):

> Don't you think the problem is

Not necessarily. It is much better to test on a real device. I would try to test on a real device that is close to what the emulator is trying to emulate.

This line

```
   at com.sunny.studios.marton.seoul.uefaquiz.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:12)
```

would make me want to look at line 12 and see if there is anything suspicious. You also get an `OutOfMemoryException`. If you are doing a lot with bitmaps then you will want to look at [Using Bitmaps Efficiently](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html). Otherwise, I would test on a few different devices to see if you have any issues. Maybe you don't have much memory allocated to your emulator. Unless I missed something.

Answer (score 1):

Actually problem is with your image you are trying to loaded. It is very large in size, emulator have limited VM memory but device have more. So it works on real device but not on emulator. Try decreasing the size of image.

Problem is here.

```
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget
```

Comment: but the image is only 300kb! is it too big?

Comment: or should I increase the sd memory of the emulator?

Comment: No, Yo need to increase VM size, sd memory is just like an external card memory.

Comment: It works thank you so muchhh!! but do you think it can cause a  problem on some older phones?

Comment: Hopefully it would not.

Answer (score 0):

What is the actual resolution of the image? Just because it's 300kb compressed, if it's, say, 1920x1080, that's 2 MegaPixels right there, which is 8MB of uncompressed bitmap (RGBA), and (IIRC) 16MB footprint due to the way Android handles overlaying.

Scale it down to something meaningful, and take advantage of the drawable-ldpi drawable-mdpi and the like directories - this way you can direct different devices to different sizes - devices with huge screens will have lots of RAM, so they can handle loading the image from drawable-xhdpi, for instance.

While for an -ldpi device, you can easily scale it down to 320x240 pixels, since that's the most common screen resolution in this class of devices.

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing the same situtation.I disabled my Antivirus( Quickheal) and it started working. Quickheal kept blocking my emulator image. [image: Click here to see the quarantine stack.]